# Questionnaire to database design

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

I have read through a lot of the threads here and have found a good amount of useful input...but there are a couple of questions that remain unanswered.

I am storing questions & answers from a questionnaire in a database.

I have the tables:

```
Survey (surveyID) 
Question (questionID, surveyID, questionType, Question) 
Answer (answerID, userID, questionID, answer) 
User (userID, username)
```

**Question 1:** multi-value questions...I would have a separate row for each value in the answer table....but have the same questionID and userID. But then how would you work the following:

-what are your coping strategies (multi-value)
-how frequently do you use each coping strategy?

i.e. a one-one relationship of coping strategy-frequency.

The solution above (i.e. one row per answer doesn't work because you need the relation between the specific coping strategy and the frequency).

A similar question is for the following:

- have you been involved in conflicts over land-use rights?

  - with whom? (multi-value)

    - for what reasons?

(i.e. what were your reasons for conflict with the neighbours, what were your reasons for conflict with the authorities?) ...i.e. one to many on a multi-value attribute

Thank you in advance, I hope I have explained my query sufficiently well.

Becky

Comment: questionnaires are IMO one of the best illustrations of how painfully limited purely relational database design really is. They're so commonplace, so simple... and so awful to model and analyse.

Comment: With "multi-value question" do you mean questions with more than one answer? In that case, can't you store one row in the answer table for each "possible choice"? As a choise was a single answer. Then you'll find rows (in the answer table) related to the same questionID (if this is you problem...)

Comment: you have a multi-value question where yes I can have a different row per answer and have the questionID...but further to this I then want to ask a question that relates to each of these answers...i.e. asking for further information for each answer. This further information could also be stored in this answer table but there is no way it can be linked to the individual value of the previous question